# Feasibility with LDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I use OpenLDAP on windows with Apache Directory Studio, and I try to set up a LDAP database that should represent hierarchically data as follow:

- root

  - users (email)

    - applications (application code)

      - companies (company code)

In order to retrieve:

1. the list of applications for a specified user
2. the list of companies for a specified user and a specified application

Do you know if it is realisable with OpenLDAP (the database creation and the searches)?

Answer (score 1):

Can you create such a model using LDAP? The answer is yes, and you can do it in multiple ways (hierachical, flat with réferences etc.).

But the thing you must understand is that LDAP is a directory not a Database :

- You can modify the base Schema to add your classes and attributs, but you do not create tables with records.
- It's operational, for data you are going to look for, but not for data that you will change a lot.

Comment: Yes I understand that LDAP is a directory and not a database, I used the wrong word to describe data structure.
The difficulty for me is how to store in a efficient way the cross value (application-company) for a user, and how to retrieve it

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to use a nearly Flat directory structure. Complex structures change and reorganization can be very difficult.

A multi-valued attributes for company and applicaitons would probably work.

-jim

Comment: By multi-valued attributes, you mean an attribute on user that lists the different combinations of pair application-company ?
For example:
User1
    member: Application1-Company1, Application1-Company2, Application2-Company1 ...